# How do I use mod_rewrite to redirect a request for a non-existent file?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have an external application (Gobi) which generates links to records in our library catalog based on the ISBN.  The application can be configured to use an URL of my devising, such as:

```
http://library.example.edu/isbn/$ISBN
```

It's then supposed to replace the `$ISBN` bit with the actual ISBN, for an URL like this:

```
http://library.example.edu/isbn/9780262516778
```

And *sometimes* it actually does that.  But other times, it takes my lovely clean URL and turns it into something like this (split out onto separate lines for your convenience):

```
http://library.example.edu/isbn/$isbn
    ?sid=ybp.com:GOBI2
    &genre=book
    &title=EVOCATIVE+OBJECTS%253a+THINGS+WE+THINK+WITH
    &isbn=9780262516778
    &date=2007
    &volume0
    &stitle=
```

These links then fail with a 404 error, because there is no file on our server named `isbn/$isbn`.  The nice short URLs are handled by mod_rewrite using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^isbn/([0-9]+)/?$  http://catalog.library.example.edu/vufind/Search/Home?lookfor=$1&type=isn&library=XMPLE    [NC,R=301,L]
```

Now I need to come up with a second rule to handle the ugly long variant.  So far I've come up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=ybp\.com:GOBI2&genre=book&title=(.*)&isbn=([0-9]*)&date=([0-9]*)&volume0&stitle=$
RewriteRule ^isbn/\$isbn.+  http://library.und.edu/test.php?lookfor=%2&type=isn&library=UNDAL    [NC,R=301,L]
```

This fails, generating an error message `File does not exist: /var/www/isbn`.  I *think* what is happening is that the RewriteRule needs a real file there, but I'm not sure.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think you have already mentioned it but I just want to double-check my understanding. Do you mean that sometimes it takes your clean URL and converts it into that long messy URL where '$isbn' occurs literally in all lower-case?

Comment: @Susam Yes, that's correct.  It sometimes puts the $isbn literally, in all lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the RewriteRule fails to match the given long URL. So, the URL passes through as un-rewritable and then Apache falls back to the default behavior of looking for a directory or file named 'isbn/$isbn' on the file system.

You should really enable rewrite logging to see these issues in your log. You can enable logging by adding this to the first line of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

along with something like this in your httpd.conf or apache2.conf:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

When you do this, you should see something like in the rewrite.log file:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:23:00:13 +051800] [susam/sid#7fa14866fe98][rid#7fa1484d80a0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/susam/www/susam.in/] add path info postfix: /home/susam/www/susam.in/isbn -> /home/susam/www/susam.in/isbn/$isbn
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:23:00:13 +051800] [susam/sid#7fa14866fe98][rid#7fa1484d80a0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/susam/www/susam.in/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/susam/www/susam.in/isbn/$isbn -> isbn/$isbn
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:23:00:13 +051800] [susam/sid#7fa14866fe98][rid#7fa1484d80a0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/susam/www/susam.in/] applying pattern '^isbn/\$isbn.+' to uri 'isbn/$isbn'
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:23:00:13 +051800] [susam/sid#7fa14866fe98][rid#7fa1484d80a0/initial] (1) [perdir /home/susam/www/susam.in/] pass through /home/susam/www/susam.in/isbn
```

Note the last but one line. The path is just `isbn/$isbn`. The query is not a part of the path. So, The `.+` you have added in the regex `^isbn/\$isbn.+` is causing the problem.

Now, how do we fix it?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=ybp\.com:GOBI2&genre=book&title=(.*)&isbn=([0-9]*)&date=([0-9]*)&volume0&stitle=$
RewriteRule ^isbn/\$isbn http://library.und.edu/test.php?lookfor=%2&type=isn&library=UNDAL    [NC,R=301,L]
```

Note that this time the regex is just `^isbn/\$isbn`.

Comment: Okay, that fixes it. It annoys me, though, that `^isbn/\$isbn` works, and `^isbn/\$isbn.+` doesn't, since I added the `.+` specifically to allow for longer URLs. I've tried `.*` on the end, and that works -- apparently the original failed because the `.+` implied that the URL had to be at least one character longer than it actually was.  Boy, mod_rewrite can be a pain sometimes.  Thanks!